# Cannot load data into table with ajax

Tags: tabulator

I am really having a hard time with upgrading my existing code from 3.5 to 4.0.5.
This time I am facing an error when I try to load data into my table with ajax calls. This did work in 3.5, so I guess something has changed in version 4. I have read the documentation carefully and read the upgrade guide. Has there been changes to the way ajax calls are made such that my code won't work like it did back in 3.5?
At last: I am using the wrapper for jquery.

The table constructor looks like this:

```
$("#PO-table").tabulator({
...columns etc
ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {


                        //url - the URL of the request
                        //params - the parameters passed with the request
                        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

                        return response.d; //Return the d Property Of a response json Object
                    },
});
```

Then I setData by adding a lot of parameters, as well as the
previously declared ajaxconfig

```
var ajaxConfig = {
                type: "POST", //set request type to Position
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type
            };

$("#PO-table").tabulator("setData", "PurchaseOrder.aspx/Fetch_PurchaseOrders", "{'POnum': '" + ponum + "', 'supplier': '" + supp + "', 'fromDate': '" + from + "', 'toDate': '" + to + "', 'spareNumber': '" + spare + "', 'isDelivered': '" + isdelivered + "', 'isConfirmedOrder': '" + true + "', 'isUnconfirmedOrder': '" + true + "', 'isExactPOnum': '" + false + "', 'isExactSupp': '" + false + "'}", ajaxConfig);
```

Then I get the error in the console and the data won't load into the table:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default Tabulator will send data in POST requests as form data, if you want to send it as JSON you will need to use the ***ajaxContentType*** option

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now", //ajax URL
    ajaxConfig:"POST", //ajax HTTP request type
    ajaxContentType:"json", // send parameters to the server as a JSON encoded string
});
```

This will encode the data as a JSON object and set the appropriate headers.

The ***ajaxContentType*** option was added in version 4.1 to make it easier for users to send requests back to their servers with a variety of content types

Comment: Yes, somehow the response is html, it seems to just fetch the whole aspx page. But why? This worked in 3.5. I include the ajaxConfig in the tabulator object, but that did not help. Seems like there are issues with fetch api. Is there anything I need to tweak in my setdata call?

Comment: as i mention in the example above the difference is the headers that are passed through. the fetch api is simply a broweser standard function for accessing xhr request functionality. i would suggest you have a look at what your request used to send in it headers in 3.5 using the debug toolbar and compare it to what is being sent in 4.0 and update the headers accordingly

Comment: Okay so when I use your code snippet in 3.5 it works fine. In 4.0 it does not work. I get errors. I compare the headers and there are differences. The request headers are 100% similar, but the response header is obviously different, the content says application/json on 3.5 and text/html on 4.0. For me this makes no sense. The aspx code behind is not being called with 4.0 so this means that the ajax fails before making the server do stuff...Is there anywhere I can provide the screenshots for my headers that I get in my network tab?

Comment: I am actually  led to believe that the problem lies in the content-type header. We promise json encoded string, but that is not what is being sent from the setdata?? I am so confused now, frustrating to never find a solution for this..

Comment: My request payload seems to include WebKitFormBoundaryxxxx before my data. Is this the problem? Do you know what this means?

Comment: have you tried including the config suggested in the answer?

Comment: Yes. The config is included. I have also tried adding 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in the headers section. My request is the same, but the payload I get back is different because I receive html for some reason...I receive my own page back(the whole aspx thing) instead of getting the purchaseOrders from the server(which works perfectly fine in 3.5).

Comment: I would suggest that you look into the serverside framework you are using and what headers it is expecting in the request. It seems like something is going very wrong serverside if it is returning raw aspx, which is very dangerous from a vulnerability point of view. you can then update the request to match

Comment: Well I use ajax, and send json to the serverside. The server side is visual basic, which in turn sends a request to a db. The method I call in vb will then return the items for my table. As I say, when I use this exact same config for 3.5 it works, and calls the vb file. In 4.0 it does not, which leads me to believe that setData no longer works like it used to. Do I have to implement the javascript way of setting data? If it indeed works like before, there is something in my config that I simply cannot figure out.

Comment: The accept header defines what the client will accept in return from the server not what is being sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182989/discussion-between-koen-and-oli-folkerd).